# Android: Phone numberformat on incoming call, determining country code?

Tags: android, number-formatting, country-codes

Im building an application that reads an incoming phonenumber, so far no problem.
But i want my app to be able to determine the country code for the incoming number if the number is international. 
 
Is there a simple solution for this?
Im uncertain if the country code always will be a fixed set of numbers, say +001 for US or only +1. If i knew that it will always be say three digist it would be very simple.
Iv taken a look at the PhoneNumberUtils class, but so far i haven't struck gold :(

Any ideas?

Regards, 
 Fredrik

Comment: Have you fixed this? I am also interested in the solution.

Comment: I ended up having to cross-check the number against a list of all know country codes. The number will always begin with the dial-out code for the country in which the call is coming to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The country code is one to three digits. There's a list at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes

The libphonenumber tools have exactly what you want.